# convert varchar to datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to filter some records by date but the datetime field seems to be stored as varchar and I'm struggling to convert it. Below is a sample of the data:

```
ID      DateField
0002    14/04/1989 01:30
0003    16/04/1989 09:45
0004    16/04/1989 06:00
0005    19/04/1989 01:07
0006    21/04/1989 16:03
```

When I use

```
cast(Datefield as datetime)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Edit - this does actually display results in datetime format but with the error message, why is that?

What's the best way to convert my datefield to valid datetime format? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CONVERT with Style

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,Datefield ,103)
```

To find bad data, see what this returns

```
set dateformat dmy
select Datefield from table where isdate(where)=0
```

You should always use proper DATETIME datatype to store datetime values

Comment: Thanks, it gives me the desired format but still with same the error message, any ideas why? Also, what does the 103 code do?

Comment: @GullitsMullet - Check [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, when I run the code above I get the following error: "
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'." do I need to replace that with a certain value?

Comment: Ah, there are some records with the format wrong e.g. "14/04/1989 : ", I've filtered these out and the convert code is working without error now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You need to add style part to identify the format

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, dates, 103)
FROM   (VALUES ('14/04/1989 01:30'),
               ('16/04/1989 09:45'),
               ('16/04/1989 06:00'),
               ('19/04/1989 01:07'),
               ('21/04/1989 16:03')) cs (dates)
```

Answer (score 1):

see  [CAST and CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

you need to use

```
select CONVERT(datetime,your_Datefield ,103)
```

because your `your_Datefield` holding the datetime value in `dd/mm/yy` format.

> follow the link, you'll get the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the error because of by default datetime format is mm/dd/yyyy. So If your value have this format, then it easily convert without error.

For this you have to convert with format which convert the string into proper date-time format. For this cast will not work , but convert work. Here is [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for more details.

As your format is dd/mm/yyyy, you need to use 103 format. Just check this to understand.

```
Select convert( datetime, getdate(), 103)
```